# Square rooting results

Tags: square-numbers

This is probably a very silly  question, but say I have $∥f∥_1^2$ (I'm trying to prove an inequality) and I square root it, do I get $-{∥f∥_1}$ and $∥f∥_1$ or just $∥f∥_1$ due to the definition of the 1 norm (beign non-negative)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have much to do with the norm.

The square root symbol $\sqrt{x}$, by convention, represents a function whose domain is $[0,\infty)$ and whose range is $[0,\infty)$. So the input $x$ must satisfy $x \ge 0$, and the output satisfies $\sqrt{x} \ge 0$.

So if, as you say, you want to compute the square root of $\|f\|_1^2$, the answer will be $\|f\|_1$.

Comment: So does that mean I would only get $∥f∥_1$?

Comment: Sorry to ask such a simple question, but with you're saying, say we take root(25), we can have -5 which is not more than or equal to 0 which you said it has to be

Comment: What I said is regarding the square root symbol, so $\sqrt{25}=5$. If you were asking about the roots to the equation $x^2=25$, then the answer would be different, those two roots are $\sqrt{25}=5$ and $-\sqrt{25}=-5$. The square root symbol itself represents a *well-defined function*. Writing $\sqrt{25}=$"$+5$ and $-5$" is not correct.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I've never noticied that before - thank you

Comment: see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310604/can-square-roots-be-negative/3310697#3310697

Comment: A subtle (be important and *REAL*) thing to note is that $x^2=25$ has *two* solutions.  But $x =\sqrt{25}$ has only one. $\sqrt{}$ is *defined* to always be non-negative.  So $\sqrt{5^2} = 5$.  And $\sqrt{(-5)^2} = 5$.  So $\sqrt{a^2}\ne a$ if $a$ is negative.  Instead $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$.  ... Important to note that if $a < 0$ then $|a| =-a$.  And $-a > 0$.  This is *NOT* a contradiction or weird.  The negative sign does *NOT* mean the value is negative.  $-(-5) =5$ and $-(negative)$ is positive. So a negative sign, $-a$ doesn't mean negative. It means *opposite* of what $a$ is.

Comment: the reason $\sqrt{∥f∥_1^2} = ∥f∥_1$ is because $∥f∥_1$ is never negative and $\sqrt{}$ is never negative.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$

If $a \ge 0$ then $\sqrt{a^2} = |a| =a$.

But if $a \le 0$ then $\sqrt{a^2} = |a| = -a$.

You have to be careful.

If you want to solve $(x+2)^2 = 9$ it is true that that means

$\sqrt{(x+2)^2} = \sqrt{9}$ which means

$|x+2| =3$ (but notice its the ABSOLUTE VALUE of $x+2$ that is equal to $3$ and *not* $x+2$ itself.

SO that means EITHER $|x+2| = x + 2 =3$ and $x = 1$ ***OR*** it could mean that $|x+2|=-(x+2)=3$ or in other words that $-x-2=3$ or we could say $x+2=-3$ and therefore $x=-5$.

So $(x+2)^2 = 9$ has two possible solution $x =1$ or $x=-5$.

THis $x^2 = M$ and $M = k^2$ for some positive $k$;  so $\sqrt {x^2} = \sqrt M$ and $|x| = k$ so $\pm x = k$ so $x= \pm k$ is so common we usually just state:

$(x+2)^2 = 9$

$(x+2) = \pm \sqrt 9 = \pm 3$.

......

But by definition $∥f∥_1$ is always positive (or $0$).

So if you have $∥f∥_1^2 = 25$ then

$\sqrt{∥f∥_1^2} = \sqrt {25} = 5$ so

$|∥f∥_1 | = 5$.

But because $∥f∥_1$ is never negative we know

$|∥f∥_1| = ∥f∥_1$.

So we have $\sqrt{∥f∥_1^2} = ∥f∥_1$ .